# A single font displaying incorrectly after moving from Win8.1 to Win10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I recently moved from Windows 8.1 to a clean install of Windows 10. To ensure I don't lose any fonts in the process, I copied all TTF and OTF files from Win 8.1 (AppData/Local) and have now reinstalled them individually through the windows font installer.

For some reason, out of all of my fonts, a font called "Estrangelo Edessa" isn't displaying properly. Below is what it looks like, in both the installer and in Word 2013:

[image: incorrect Estrangelo Edessa font]

And this is what it should actually look like:

[image: correct Estrangelo Edessa font]

It seems to be borrowing two different typefaces to display letters and numbers, with odd letter-spacing (most noticeable for capital letters).

I know too little about how Windows handles fonts to figure out what could be wrong with this particular font, which worked fine on the previous Win8.1 installation, with the same TTF file. I'm currently guessing I must have installed at some point, over a 6 year period, some Windows component that interacts with this font, but I haven't been able to find what that could be.